# Drop the first (or any nth) column whose name contains a specific string from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]],columns=['a1693','b1124','b113','a2609', 'a1'])
```

I want to drop, for example, `b1124`. How do I do it?

I can get the column as a pd.Series by using the following code.

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('b')].iloc[:,0]
```

But I don't know how to drop it from `df`.

Also, if I want to do the same for multiple columns, i.e. drop `a1693` and `b1124`, how do I do that as well?

Comment: ``df.drop("b1124", axis=1)`` ? you probably have something more than this in mind, so maybe explain a bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add filter

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('b')][0],1)
   a1693  b113  a2609  a1
0      1     3      4   5
1      6     8      9  10
```

Comment: it excludes the ``b113`` as well. I feel, and I may be wrong, that the OP needs a programmatic way to get the `nth` column based on a string

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Now, if I want to do the same for multiple columns, is there a better way than the following: 

`for var in ['a','b']:
    
    df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(var)][0], axis=1, inplace=True)
`

Comment: @YOBEN_S is so good at answering Pandas questions, he knows what the OP wants before OP does =)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [28]: N = 0

In [29]: df.drop(df.columns[np.where(df.columns.str.contains("b")==True)[0][N]], axis=1)
Out[29]:
   a1693  b113  a2609  a1
0      1     3      4   5
1      6     8      9  10

In [30]: N = 1

In [31]: df.drop(df.columns[np.where(df.columns.str.contains("b")==True)[0][N]], axis=1)
Out[31]:
   a1693  b1124  a2609  a1
0      1      2      4   5
1      6      7      9  10
```